# CiviBuild - wp-demo install error with postdrop

Tags: civibuild

I am trying to use civibuild for installing a wp-demo instance on my local machine. I am using XAMPP on macOS Sierra.

The download successfully completed:

`civibuild download "civiwpbuild" --civi-ver "master" --type "wp-demo"`

But while running install:

`civibuild install "civiwpbuild" --url "http://localhost:4000" --admin-pass "XXXXXXXXXX"`

It gets stuck with:

`postdrop: warning: mail_queue_enter: create file maildrop/29895.24374: No such file or directory`

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the fix that my `postfix` was not running.

I had to do a `sudo postfix start` which resulted in a number of warnings with final output

`postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system`

After this I retried running the civibuild install

`civibuild install "civiwpbuild" --url "http://localhost:4000" --admin-pass "XXXXXXXXXX"`

and it worked.

More details on postdrop: http://www.postfix.org/postdrop.1.html